# Ubuntu KVM Bridged DHCP nothing works

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I have looked at questions here and every tutorial I can find on google and nothing seems to fix my issue. I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server that has a bunch of software on it (Unifi, Unifi Video, UNMS, Bluecherry, Apache2). I need a software that only supports 14.04 (mFi). SO I have software that updates on 16.04 only and software that won't work on 16.04 but for electric bill reasons needs to be on 1 PC. I have the 16.04 running KVM and can install a VM just fine. I also have a br0 created that receives DHCP from my router. I need the 14.04 VM to also get DHCP from my router. On host ifconfig looks like this:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:c0:38:c5:42
      inet addr:10.11.11.254  Bcast:10.11.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21c:c0ff:fe38:c542/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:77330 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:48141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:97552697 (97.5 MB)  TX bytes:31018242 (31.0 MB)

br-441049093d8f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:29:9b:ba:1c
      inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:29ff:fe9b:ba1c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:84 (84.0 B)  TX bytes:8560 (8.5 KB)

br-f26207b68430 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:62:fb:8a:5e
      inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:172.19.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:62ff:fefb:8a5e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:55749 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:47179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:7779523 (7.7 MB)  TX bytes:26110547 (26.1 MB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:1e:8a:a7:a3
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:c0:38:c5:42
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14320804 errors:0 dropped:88 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9161214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:18267999423 (18.2 GB)  TX bytes:4224704433 (4.2 GB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:e8200000-e8220000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:455114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:455114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:323006260 (323.0 MB)  TX bytes:323006260 (323.0 MB)

veth6087736 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 92:6b:9e:30:3f:3f
      inet6 addr: fe80::906b:9eff:fe30:3f3f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:631966 (631.9 KB)  TX bytes:451342 (451.3 KB)

veth0be9933 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f6:4b:44:26:95:31
      inet6 addr: fe80::f44b:44ff:fe26:9531/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:22962 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:23170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1511612 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:6634025 (6.6 MB)

veth4721a38 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:30:ad:6b:99:c9
      inet6 addr: fe80::a430:adff:fe6b:99c9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:51401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:48796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:23393519 (23.3 MB)  TX bytes:22044039 (22.0 MB)

veth4bfc810 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 96:a8:06:b1:01:21
      inet6 addr: fe80::94a8:6ff:feb1:121/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:35421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:38362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:38357384 (38.3 MB)  TX bytes:27451189 (27.4 MB)

veth670940c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ba:ee:fa:d6:a2:3f
      inet6 addr: fe80::b8ee:faff:fed6:a23f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:53627 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:44489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:38465696 (38.4 MB)  TX bytes:49446336 (49.4 MB)

vethd484c2b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:53:04:68:c2:d1
      inet6 addr: fe80::3453:4ff:fe68:c2d1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:26617 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:20841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:4291112 (4.2 MB)  TX bytes:18090223 (18.0 MB)

vethda042e9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:6b:69:35:34:34
      inet6 addr: fe80::346b:69ff:fe35:3434/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:10448286 (10.4 MB)  TX bytes:10590365 (10.5 MB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:88:62:21
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:71 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:586 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:11162 (11.1 KB)  TX bytes:53777 (53.7 KB)
```

There is also a docker software installed for one of the programs, but I'm pretty sure the other stuff is from the endless attempts.

My Host etc/network/interfaces looks like this at the moment (again in my endless attempts):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# bridge interface for kvm
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 vnet1 vnet0 vethda042e9 vethd484c2b veth670940c veth4bfc810 veth4721a38 veth0be9933 veth6087736
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Will this actually work or am I looking at reinstalling everything to esxi? VMware does this. Virtualbox does this. Why can I not create a L2 bridge between the Ethernet and the VM? Pretty sure I could probably even do this with Windows Hypervisor.

Firewall is disabled.
Don't have anything from VMs because after a while it was a complete waste of time if the failed on DHCP before installing everything.
Tried installing via Terminal.
Setup another Desktop Ubuntu to install Virtual Network Manager on and install from that about 9 times

Yes I am using libvirt. Originally the only interface that was added to br0 was eth0 but still got no DHCP. I started adding the other ones hoping that might work but nope.

Here is xml:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='11'>
  <name>mFi</name>
  <uuid>096832a0-76bf-488c-88dd-f0bcae02046c</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-xenial'>hvm</type>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>core2duo</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/mFi.img'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' 
function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/boot/ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' 
function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' 
function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' 
function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' 
function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' 
function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' 
function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:88:62:21'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <boot order='3'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' 
function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/0'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' 
function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' 
function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' 
function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor' relabel='yes'>
    <label>libvirt-096832a0-76bf-488c-88dd-f0bcae02046c</label>
    <imagelabel>libvirt-096832a0-76bf-488c-88dd-f0bcae02046c</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

When I try to edit the config, it shows this:

```
  <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:88:62:21'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <boot order='3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' 
function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Even thought the dump showed alis and target. They are not here to take out. Wouldn't let me do this in comments.

Host is not this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# bridge interface for kvm
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

No idea what you mean by guest network config, isn't that what we just checked?

Comment: You don't need to add all the VM interfaces to `bridge_ports`. Libvirt will do that itself. You _are_ using libvirt, right? Somehow these details were omitted from your question.

Comment: So what is the VM's network configuration? Paste the XML.

Comment: Where might I find that?

Comment: `virsh dumpxml vmname`

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your VM's network interface configuration.

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:88:62:21'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <boot order='3'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' 
function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

First, `<target>` is optional when bridging to an existing bridge; you shouldn't normally specify it at all. I would remove this line.

Second, you have defined an `<alias>`, but the `name` attribute is wrong. All alias names must start with the literal string `ua-`. This option did not exist prior to libvirt 3.9.0. It is also optional, so you could just delete it.

Edit the VM with `virsh edit vmname`. You must stop and start the VM again for settings to take effect, if it was running at the time it's edited.

Beyond that, if that doesn't get the VM on the network, the problem is most likely going to be in the guest configuration or in the local physical network (e.g. the upstream switch).

Comment: Edited to reply

Comment: Also moved it from switch directly to Mikrotik Router. Still same.

Comment: OK, you should skip all this and go directly to checking your guest networking configuration and your local physical network.

Comment: @ShaneBecker The guest is the operating system you are running inside the virtual machine.

Comment: Its the Ubuntu installer cd trying to get DHCP, what is there to check.

Comment: @ShaneBecker Then this doesn't make any sense. Have you restarted networking on the host (or rebooted it) since fixing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file? If not, I would do that now.

Comment: I have rebooted it. I know it doesn't make sense. That's why I'm here. I followed a bunch of tutorials and rechecked stuff and tried other stuff before I started this question. Nothing is working as I have been told and read.